# Icons in dired mode for Emacs

Tags: emacs, dired

I would like to use the dired mode of emacs as my file browser. I am very much addicted to see an icon for file/folder rather that to see the extension and color. The icons give me a very quick visual feedback. I have searched the web for display of icons in dired but found none. So I wonder whether it is even possible to do this and if yes how?

To put my question clearly

How can I display icons for files and folders in dired mode of Emacs?

Comment: I have come a long way since I asked this question. Here is my emacs config as of today - https://github.com/amolgawai/emacsadventures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Windows, you can try `dired-dispicon.el`.
Get the relevant files from [here](http://ring.riken.jp/archives/elisp/gohome/junk/).
See http://wiki.gohome.org/teranisi/?EmacsOnWindows for what it looks like. Note that you will probably need a version of emacs that supports images (e.g. for Windows you could try [EmacsW32](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html)).

Comment: I did find this, but seems to be working on EmacsW32 and not NTEmacs. I basically want this behavior for accessing files on a Linux server. I intend to connect to the Linux server, open emacs to do most of the things. I don't want a separate file browser to be opened this way. On Windows, I am ok with default File Browser (Explorer).

Comment: This is close enough answer. Although I am using Xfe for Linux File browsing.

Comment: The link's broken.

Comment: ```all-the-icons-dired.el``` is another approach. https://github.com/jtbm37/all-the-icons-dired I confirmed it works on macOS.

Answer (score 4):

[all-the-icons-dired](https://github.com/jtbm37/all-the-icons-dired) is a more current solution. Another option that looks quite nice is to use [treemacs-icons-dired](https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs#treemacs-icons-dired)

I just switched to treemacs-icons-dired and recommend it. Simply install the package and add a mode hook like:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'treemacs-icons-dired-mode)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am already using all-the-icons and treemacs. If you are interested take a look at my emacs config - https://github.com/amolgawai/emacsadventures

Comment: Looks very nice!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [dired-icon](https://gitlab.com/xuhdev/dired-icon) extension, which works for GTK (on Linux).

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the extension.